# How to specify xml namespace is SVG for ui-router partial templates?

Tags: angularjs, svg, angular-ui-router, xml-namespaces

for the first time I have not found any solution to a problem I am encountering while developing a web app with AngularJS and UI-router.

The issue : 
partial templates made of SVG elements are not created within the correct namespace and therefore are not displayed on some browsers - namely FF, Safari (I haven't tried on latest IE). 
Note that the issue doesn't arise in Chrome nor Opera where all elements are rendered properly.

I have been able to reproduce the issue with a simple Plunkr:
 (http://plnkr.co/edit/u3mfJD9I2EuZ6wbfl4B6).

```
index.html
<body>
  <h1>nested States</h1>
  <div ui-view="home"></div>
</body>

home
<svg height="500px" width="500px">
    <g ui-view="nested"></g>
</svg>

nested 
<g ng-repeat="x in [1,2,4,5]">
  <text x="50" y="{{50*x}}">text in ng repeat is somehow OK</text>
  <g ui-view="circle"></g>
</g>
<g>
  <text x="10" y="15">I am not interpreted as SVG</text>
</g>

circle
<circle r="10" cx="30" ng-attr-cy="{{50*x}}"></circle>
```

Inspecting elements properties I find they have **proto** : HTMLUnknownElementPrototype

A few things I gathered while struggling/investigating :

- somehow ng-repeat seems find its way around the issue for its direct children tags, as shown in my plunkr.
- There was a known bug in previous Angular Versions whereby SVG nodes would not be created properly in ngInclude templates, much like in my example. This specific issue seemed to be related to something called innerHtml (a concept I need to research) and was fixed. This might be why ngRepeat direct children work properly. I am wildly extrapolating here ... truth is I have no idea.
- this lead me into thinking the issue is maybe more related to ui-router than angular itself.

Any help will be appreciated, 
Many thanks,
J.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML 5 specification changed the way innerHTML works not so long ago to try to better accommodate SVG.

UAs are catching up with the specification change, Chrome was the first to do, Firefox will work the way you want (and your example will work) from version 36 onwards (currently in Beta, releasing on 24 Feb 2015). Safari and IE will likely catch up too at some point.

In the meantime you'd need to use javascript to recreate the elements in the correct namespace.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson!! Even better a response than what I was expecting. Luckily I can wait.